# Does this "fleeing spiders leaving fields of webs" phenomenon have a name?

Tags: arachnology

I have recently seen images of big areas covered in spider webs:

- After flood in Australia

  - http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2012/03/pictures/120307-spiderwebs-australia-floods-wagga-wagga-world-science/#/spider-webs-australia-floods-bush_49725_600x450.jpg
  - http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2111390/Australia-floods-Spiders-cover-fields-cobwebs-flee-rising-water.html
  - http://www.hoax-slayer.com/spider-fields-australian-floods.shtml
  - http://www.theatlantic.com/infocus/2012/03/spiders-flee-australian-flood/100265/
  - http://io9.com/5891091/massive-spiderwebs-engulf-australian-town-as-arachnids-escape-floods

I would like to read about this on wikipedia. So I am looking for a name of this phenomenon. Do you know how it is called?

Comment: I doubt it will be called anything specific. It's just spiders fleeing a flood like any other animal.